# how can I use a function I define in a new function I define?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

My first function I defined that works

```
def chainPoints(aa,DIS,SEG,H):
#xtuple
    n=0
    xterms = []
    xterm = -DIS
    while n<=SEG:
        xterms.append(xterm)
        n+=1
        xterm = -DIS + n*SEGL
#
#ytuple
    k=0
    yterms = []
    while k<=SEG:
        yterm = H + aa*m.cosh(xterms[k]/aa) - aa*m.cosh(DIS/aa)
        yterms.append(yterm)
        k+=1
```

But now I need a second function that depends on my first function, speciffically the lists xterms and yterms.

```
def chainLength(aa,DIS,SEG,H):
    chainPoints(aa,DIS,SEG,H)

#length of chain
    ff=1
    Lterm=0.
    totallength=0.
    while ff<=SEG:
        Lterm = m.sqrt((xterms[ff]-xterms[ff-1])**2 + (yterms[ff]-yterms[ff-1])**2)
        totallength += Lterm
        ff+=1
return(totallength)
```

I had it all done without defined functions, but now I need to have defined functions for each part.

Comment: Why did you just update your question with my answer? Are you saying that you already did this or do you have a follow-up question? If so, do *not* invalidate the answer by updating your question to follow.

Comment: sorry, some guy told me to update questions previously. Still a noob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *return* results from your `chainPoints()` function, then assign the return value to local name(s) in your `chainLength()` function:

```
def chainPoints(aa, DIS, SEG, H):
    #xtuple
    n = 0
    xterms = []
    xterm = -DIS
    while n <= SEG:
        xterms.append(xterm)
        n += 1
        xterm = -DIS + n * SEGL
    #
    #ytuple
    k = 0
    yterms = []
    while k <= SEG:
        yterm = H + aa * m.cosh(xterms[k] / aa) - aa * m.cosh(DIS / aa)
        yterms.append(yterm)
        k += 1

    return xterms, yterms


def chainLength(aa, DIS, SEG, H):
    xterms, yterms = chainPoints(aa, DIS, SEG, H)

    ff = 1
    Lterm = 0.
    totallength = 0.
    while ff <= SEG:
        Lterm = m.sqrt((xterms[ff] - xterms[ff-1]) ** 2 + 
                       (yterms[ff] - yterms[ff - 1]) ** 2)
        totallength += Lterm
        ff += 1

    return totallength
```

I used the same names in `chainLength` here, but that is not a requirement.

Comment: okay, but how do I use my chainLength function? I don't know what to put for xterms and yterms arguments?

Comment: @BobUnger: I spelled it out for you some more.